# Whitelisted parameters do not appear in strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have the following problem, I've tried to resolve it using Google, but it didn't give any noticeable results.

I have form for updating **Model** and I've been trying to add new parameters to strong parameters (*model_params*) and it seems like they are not including these params, event though their values appear in regular **params** (used *byebug* to check them out)

```
def model_params
   params.require(:model).permit(
    :id, # new param
    :hidden_field_param, # also new one
     # Long list of parameters omitted
    nested_model_attributes: [:id, :file, :_destroy])
end
```

**params**

```
<ActionController::Parameters { All parameters including new and old ones } permitted: false>
```

**model_params**

```
<ActionController::Parameters { Only old ones } permitted: true>
```

Thank you.

**UPD**

**_form.html.erb** (partial)

```
<%= form_for @model, :remote => true, :authenticity_token => true, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>

    <!-- All other fields omitted, they are working correctly -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <%= hidden_field_tag :hidden_field_param, 'Here is string value' %>
            <% count = 0 %>
            <%= f.fields_for :nested_model, method: :post, class: "" do |ff| %>
                <%= ff.file_field :file, multiple: true, id: 'pictures_' + (count=count+1).to_s, class: "image_item" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
       <%= f.submit 'Done', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your view file too?

Comment: Sure, here it is

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your hidden field tag is called as "hidden_field" and not "hidden_field_param". Also you don't need to mention :id while saving to database since it is auto-increment. Your model params should look like this:

```
def model_params
   params.require(:model).permit(
     :hidden_field,
     # Long list of parameters omitted
   nested_model_attributes: [:id, :file])
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my mistake, when posting here. I've re-checked name of hidden_field param in **_form** partial and in **controller**, they are same, so, that shouldn't be the reason.

Comment: Also, shouldn't I pass :id of model to `@model = Model.find(model_params[:id])` in **update** action? Hence, :id should be whitelisted, no?

Comment: Yes you do need id in update action but not in model params. ID is used to only find a record

Comment: So it is safe to just use weak params? `@model = Model.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Yes in update function. Strong params are used when you do mass assignment while creating and updating

Comment: Finally, cleared that out. Thank you! So, how about main problem? I'm still trying to figure out why **hidden_param** appears in list of parameters, but, even though I have whitelisted it, do not includes in the strong ones.